# Plotting a proportion bar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying get a stacked barchart using ggplot2 where each bar shows gdp contibution of the countries in that continent.

However, the best I could do was to get the bars equally divided by the number of countries in that continent's gdp. My code and resultant graphs are given below.

```
gapminder %>% 
  mutate(gdp = pop * gdpPercap) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = continent, weight =sum(gdp), 
                           fill = country), color = "black") +
    guides(fill = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw()
```

The output I am getting now with the above code:
[image]

Gapminder Dataset
[image]

Expected result(It should look similar to this):
[image]

Comment: What's the data structure of `gapminder`? Also, please provide a reproducible example and the expected output.

Comment: You're not assigning `gdp` to the y-variable, so each bar is just a count of countries.

Comment: @adam Updated the question.

Comment: There is no option to add a y variable to a barchart

Comment: There is very much an option to add the y-variable, as the accepted answer illustrates :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you have to work, you need to either set `stat = "identity"` in `geom_bar` or just use `geom_col`. You'll also need to filter to a single year for each country, or you'll get sections for each year for each country.

```r
library(tidyverse)

gapminder::gapminder %>% 
    mutate(gdp = pop * gdpPercap) %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    filter(year == max(year)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = gdp, fill = country)) + 
    geom_col(color = "black", size = 0.2) +
    guides(fill = FALSE) + 
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a great use case for stacked bars. Trying to assign a colour palette to 142 countries just creates a rainbow mess.

Can I suggest a treemap instead.

```
library(treemap)
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>% 
  filter(year == 2007) %>%
  mutate(gdp = pop * gdpPercap) %>% 
  treemap(., c("continent", "country"), "gdp", algorithm = "squarified")
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I agree that it is not the best way to visualise the data but I wanted to show the proportions in a barchart if possible. Just to show which countries contriubte the highest